# How to navigate to next page using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So im trying to navigate to a web page after signing in, and when i execute the code, it signs in but never navigates to the next page. I have tried navigating to the next page in the same function, and in seperate, but it doesn't move onto the next one. On MacOS Big Sur using Pycharm, python 3.9.

*I left out the authentication code, but cannot get the driver to navigate to a page after the sign in page.

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2F%3Fref_%3Dnav_signin&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071FXZBMV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1')
```

```
def amazon_login_buy():
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2F%3Fref_%3Dnav_signin&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&')
    # enter email here
    driver.find_element_by_id('ap_email').send_keys('')
    driver.find_element_by_id('continue').click()
    # enter password here
    driver.find_element_by_id('ap_password').send_keys('')
    driver.find_element_by_name('rememberMe').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit').click()


def amazon_navigate():
    # driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071FXZBMV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1')


amazon_login_buy()

amazon_navigate()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "never navigates to the next page"?
I see only 2 `driver.get()` method calls here.

Comment: Sorry I added a comment, but I will add the authentication code to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you get some error? What exactly happens on the second `driver.get()` call?

Comment: I dont get an error, it just never navigates to the second link via the driver.get method. It stops at the amazon homepage.

Comment: I am not sure why you would do separate `get` calls here.  Why not log into the original log-in URL and then click/search your way to the product page you want to end up at?

Comment: When you login manually, how do you navigate to the next page?

Comment: I can but wouldn't that be more complicated rather than just a direct link? I am new to coding so I am unsure of best practice here.

Comment: Nope, not more complicated and in fact it's the way to handle this exact scenario.

Comment: thanks. so fom the page provided, its best to use the search bar and navigate via input?

Comment: @Drizzmo.  Exactly, thats the whole point of using Selenium.  Navigating around like you normally would.  See my example answer below.  You'll need to learn how to find elements on the webpage etc obviously.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can navigate to that item (minus all the log in stuff), without using multiple `get` calls.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def amazon_login_buy():

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com')
    textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
    textbox.send_keys("OHill Cable Clips,16 Pack Black Adhesive Cord Holders, Ideal Cable Cords Management for Organizing Cable Wires-Home, Office, Car, Desk Nightstand")
    textbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    item = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result'])[3]//img")))
    item.click()



amazon_login_buy()
```

You could probably get away with a shorter search word as well for `send_keys`, you'd have to play around with that.

Basically it will:

1. Go to Amazon.com
2. Search for the item you want in the search box
3. Click the image of the item from the resulting list of items. I was guessing which one you actually wanted, you can experiment with that piece.  I chose the 1st one down that wasn't "sponsored".

Comment: Why would you search in the UI and then click a product link when you already know the URL of the product you want??? I'm sure he's not working at amazon as a tester so why use the UI when you don't have to? You have to write more code, you have to potentially deal with more issues if the UI updates, etc.

Comment: @JeffC I was giving him another more flexible option. Is he going to have the exact URL for every single item he wants to look at? I doubt it.  The way he has it set up, he is initiating 2 get methods, one for logging in and then one for a specific product? it doesn't make sense, and I can see why his code won't work that way. I was just showing him a way to navigate around Amazon without needing an actual product link every single time.  That seems inefficient to me.  Why use the UI if he doesn't have to? No argument there, he should go entirely through the API though  if that's the case.

Comment: I learned to use it both ways: one way for products I already knew the link to, and others that I needed to find. For links I knew, I would navigate directly to the page and login via the sign in option at the top. For unknown, authentication then browsing was my approach.